# subprocess.Popen output: how to overcome the differences with commandline execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, grep, subprocess, cygwin

I am working on a Python script to compare two files. Therefore I have chosen to work with `grep` as an external program, launching the following two commands:

```
grep -Fvf content1.txt content2.txt
grep -Fvf content2.txt content1.txt
```

From the results of those commands gives me the differences, I can extract the amount of differences by counting the amount of lines.

In order to execute this in a Python script, I have embedded those `grep` commands in `subprocess.Popen()` functions:

```
try:
    output1, errors1 = subprocess.Popen(
        ["c:\\cygwin\\bin\\grep", "-Fvf", "content1.txt", "content2.txt"],
        shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()

    output2, errors2 = subprocess.Popen(
        ["c:\\cygwin\\bin\\grep", "-Fvf", "content2.txt", "content1.txt"],
        shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()

    if (len(output1) + len(output2) + len(errors1) + len(errors2) > 0):
        print("Result : there are differences:")

        if (len(output1) + len(output2) > 0):
            print("  Output differences : ")
            print(output1)
            # print (str(str(output1).count('\n'))); (*)
            print(output2)
            # print (str(str(output2).count('\n'))); (*)
            if (len(errors1) + len(errors2) > 0):
                print("  Errors : ")
                print(errors1)
                print(errors2)
            else:
                print("Result : both are equal")

except Exception as ex:
    print("Result : Exception during comparison:")
    print(ex)
    raise
```

I have put the two problematic lines in comment (the ones who end with `(*)`).

As you can see the problem is the following:

- When I launch the command in a command prompt, the result which I get is a bunch of strings. By counting the amount of those strings I can get the result that I want (e.g. using a `wc -l`).
- When I launch the command in a Python script, the result which I get (`output1` and `output2`) are bytes instead of strings.

  I had hoped that a simple typecast to a string would give me the opportunity to count for the number of newline characters and hence, count the number of differences, but this would have been too easy.

I have tried using the `wc -l` but pipes inside of `subprocess.Popen()` seem not to be a good idea.

How I can handle the `output1` and `output2` results in order to search for the number of differences?

Comment: I see you're using cygwin, you might want to try adding `universal_newlines=True` to the subprocess.Popen calls.

Comment: Have you a special reason for using external grep instead of the `difflib` module from standard library?

Comment: unrelated: you could use `r'c:\cygwin\bin\grep.exe'` (raw string literal) for Windows paths. Drop `shell=True` and pass the full path to `grep.exe` (including the file extension).

Comment: Have you considered `comm  -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using python 3.x (you don't specify 2.7 vs 3.x but in 2.7, `subprocess.communicate()` returns a tuple of two strings-or-None values, while in 3.x it returns a tuple of two bytes-or-None values, and you said specifically "bytes"):

```
$ python3
...
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> res = proc.communicate()[0]
>>> type(res)
<class 'bytes'>
>>>
```

vs:

```
$ python2
...
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> res = proc.communicate()[0]
>>> type(res)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

This is because python3 uses Unicode for all its strings (instead of trying to use strings for both byte-sequences and "stringy" things).

There are two obvious ways to deal with this.

- Work with the bytes as bytes:

  ```
  >>> res.count(b'\n')
  382
  >>> print(res.splitlines())[0])
  b'COPYING'
  ```

  (This method also works in Python 2.7, the b'\n' is just '\n'.)
- Convert the input to Unicode.  I'm not very up on Python3 and am not sure of the Best Way to do this, but this seems pretty good:

  ```
  >>> stringy = res.decode('utf-8') # or whatever encoding your system uses
  >>> print(type(stringy), stringy.splitlines()[0])
  <class 'str'> COPYING
  ```

Or, you can have Python convert the piped output to Unicode strings by setting `universal_newlines=True`; see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Or, of course, you can use Python 2 :-) (I still do for various compatibility reasons)

Comment: `splitlines(ord(b'\n'))` is misleading. The argument is a boolean `keepends` i.e., you want `splitlines(True)` instead. Also, it is easy to write code that works the same on Python 2 and 3 here e.g., `.count(b'\n')` works on both Python 2.7 and Python 3 or pass `universal_newlines=True` to enable text mode.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: ah, as I said I'm not very up on Python 3.  Will update answer.

Answer (score 5):

Don't call `str()` on bytes. It is almost always an error.

To enable text mode, pass `universal_newlines=True` to `subprocess.Popen()`.

Or you could work with bytes directly e.g., use `.count(b'\n')` instead of `.count('\n')`.

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted, but I counter-balanced it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pipe it to the unix tool `diff` :

```
diff <(grep "^@" myfile1) <(grep "^@" myfile2)
```

You can call this in your `popen` command.

Comment: I am working on a Windows 7 environment, where I have a "C:\Cygwin" directory, containing the "grep" tool. However I don't seem to have a "diff" tool there.

Comment: install it from setup.exe then. diff is an essential tool in cygwin.

Comment: @Dominique Maybe add these to your question is a good idea :)